# Google Maps Javascript API call function on dragend after minimum distance change

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am calling functions to clear the current markers on the map, then search for new markers with the same request, once the user has stopped dragging the map. This works great, except it's a little annoying if you only drag the map a small distance.

So I'm looking for a way to only call the functions on **dragend** *after* the user has moved the map center 500 meters from the previous position, or maybe only after the user has dragged the previous map center out of the map bounds.

Thanks in advance for any tips!

```js
// Update results after drag
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'dragend',function(event) {
    clearMarkers();
    findPlaces();
});
```

Comment: I guess **center_changed** would be better than **dragend**, but the real question is how to call the function after some kind of minimum change?

Answer (score 0):

Well, keep your original center latlng, and calculate the distance to the updated latlng either using the distance service API, or this [site](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) , or the [Pythagorean theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) for a small distance, and only fire if the distance is greater than a number.

Comment: Great answer. You could also use the Spherical Geometry Library in the Maps API to calculate that distance: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for calling something after map is dragged a minimum, assuming you haved stored the original geopoint

```js
// Calculate distace from map center after drag
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'dragend',function(event) {
    var p1 = new google.maps.LatLng(40.69847032728747, -73.9514422416687);
    var p2 = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    if ((calcDistance(p1, p2)) > 50) {
      // Do something
      alert(calcDistance(p1, p2));
    }

    //calculates distance between two points in km's
    function calcDistance(p1, p2){
      return (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(p1, p2) / 1000).toFixed(2);
    }
    var releaseLoc = event.latLng.lat() + ', ' + event.latLng.lng();
    alert(releaseLoc);
});
```